# How do I unblock downloaded files in Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: windows-8-preview

In Windows 7 you could unblock downloaded files by right-clicking and use the Unblock button in the properties dialog, this has been removed from Windows 8.

Now I need to unblock zip-files with files to use them but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. Or at least a way to do it without too much work. No GUI way found so that needs to be solved but this works.

To unblock a downloaded file, run the Unblock-File PowerShell 3.0 commandlet!

Like this:

```
Unblock-File .\php_manual_en.chm
```