# Unblocking link - no buttons?

Tags: windows-8.1

So I have an issue similar to the guys over at:

- [here](https://superuser.com/questions/191830/windows-vista-open-file-security-warning-on-local-exe-unblock-does-not-w) - not in program files folder
- [here](https://superuser.com/questions/400787/how-do-i-unblock-downloaded-files-in-windows-8-consumer-preview) - I would rather not download a shell just to unblock a link
- and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/38476/this-file-came-from-another-computer-how-can-i-unblock-all-the-files-in-a/570913#570913) - I didn't have a zip and I don't need to bulk unblock anything

But the answers given to them don't suit my question.
I have a toolbar on my taskbar that points to my Favorites folder.
I put a link to a python program that I wrote, and whenever I click it, this is what happens:

[image: The popup and Properties]

On the left is the popup, as you can see there isn't a "don't show again" button, and on the right side is the properties of the file, there isn't an "unblock" button under "advanced" either, so I pretty much don't know what to do...

The popup is very annoying and sometimes takes around 10 seconds to even appear, so removing it would really help me.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Similar issue, mat be a registry setting, or maybe its the python launcher that is being blocked, not the actual lnk file....http://superuser.com/questions/503812/how-to-unblock-chm-files-unblock-button-is-missing

Comment: @Moab if i open file location and click the file itself, it opens OK... So I don't think the python launcher is blocked